# Error with using NRPE with Icinga2

Tags: icinga

I have working instance of Nagios, and I would like to run Icinga2 on other machine. Nagios is using NRPE so I would like to use it too.

I have following configuration in files:

```
object Service "NRPE check load" {
    import "generic-service"
    host_name = "agrippina"
    check_command = "nrpe-check-2arg"
    vars.host = "agrippina.domain.net"
    vars.check = "check_load"
    vars.loads = "'10' '20'"
    }
```

and

```
object CheckCommand "nrpe-check-2arg" {
    import "plugin-check-command"
    command = [PluginDir + "/check_nrpe" ]
    arguments = {
    "-H" = "$host$"
    "-c" = "$check$"
    "-a" = "$loads$"
    }
}
```

When I'm issuing command by hand:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H agrippina.domain.net -c 'check_load' -a '10' '20'
```

I receive

> OK - load average: 0.98, 1.39, 3.79|load1=0.980;10.000;20.000;0;
>   load5=1.390;10.000;20.000;0; load15=3.790;10.000;20.000;0;

Icinga2 logs:

```
CHECK_NRPE: Received 0 bytes from daemon.  Check the remote server logs for error messages.
```

Where should I look for that messages?

Since when I run this check by hand and it works, how to fix it in Icinga2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `vars.loads = "'10' '20'"` to `vars.loads = "10!20"` because NRPE is not able to read the arguments the way you have declared them in object Service.

Comment: Why? How? Please elaborate.

Comment: Because NRPE is not able to read the arguments the way you have declared them in object Service.
Put
vars.loads = "10!20"
instead of 
vars.loads = "'10' '20'" 

reload icinga2 and verify the result.

Comment: Enter this in the answer, as a comment it will be soon deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create custom CheckCommand definitions for multiple use cases. We've wrapped our heads into making CheckCommand objects more re-usable during our development cycles, and one thing you'll get - optional and also conditional arguments.

http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/monitoring-basics#command-arguments

Furthermore, icinga2 already ships the 'nrpe' plugin check command definition, also allowing you do add multiple additional arguments -a) passed as array.

http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/plugin-check-commands#plugin-check-command-nrpe

Your example:

vars.nrpe_arguments = [ 10, 20 ]

Better go that way, and in case you'll have more CheckCommand definitions to share, please send them upstream - it certainly helps to not care about CheckCommand definitions but only hosts/servics and their custom attributes used as comnand parameters :)

https://wiki.icinga.org/display/community/Contribute+Icinga+2+ITL+Plugin+Check+Command+Definitions